# Add new icon in Calendar View to download a ICS file

Tags: calendar

I have a Sharepoint calendar with a lot of events, I need to allow the user download an ICS calendar file by clicking on each event through the Calendar View. My idea is to add a new Icon **Download ICS** as the following image.

[image]

I've added a new column to my calendar and following [this](http://virtualducttape.com/generating-an-ical-ics-file-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-list-item/) post  I have a link that allows me to download the ICS file. 
But it's necessary to open the event and do it from the DisplayForm.

I would like to avoid it and add a new icon on each event in my Calendar View.

I tried displaying my new column instead of title in the calendar view, but the link always redirect me to the `DisplayForm`.